# How to convert a function based program to class concept in python

Tags: python

I have a program,But that not contain class concept ( Python program follow some value to class concept) am really a new one in python world. So learning from the original way help me out to shine in this world. Can anyone kindly help me out, instead of making this question negative mark :(

```
 import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
 import sys

doc       = ET.parse("books.xml")
root      = doc.getroot() 
root_new  = ET.Element("books") 
for child in root:
    name                = child.attrib['name']
    cost                = child.attrib['cost']
    # create "book" here
    book    = ET.SubElement(root_new, "book") 
    book.set("name",name)               
    book.set("cost",cost) 
    if 'color' in child.attrib:
        color               = child.attrib['color']
        book.set("color",color) 
    if 'weight' in child.attrib:
        weight              = child.attrib['weight']
        book.set("weight",weight)
    for g in child.findall("cover"):
        # create "group" here
       cover     = ET.SubElement(cover,"cover")  
        if g.text != "goldcover":
            cover.text = g.text 
tree = ET.ElementTree(root_new)
tree.write(sys.stdout)
```

For understanding : my xml is ,

```
<books>
<book name="goodbook" cost="10" color="green"></book>
<book name="badbook" cost="1000" weight="100"><cover>papperback</cover><cover>hardcover</cover></book>
<book name="avgbook" cost="99" weight="120"></book>
</books>
```

As a fresher on python i hope some one will help me out , All valuable input are warmly welcomed.

Comment: Could you clear up what your question is exactly? Do you want to make the above code into a Python Class?

Comment: i need to to treat the xml as class member data or a constant value, via it can reusable r8

Comment: Your example seems to parse an XML in order to create an identical-looking XML? There is no non-transient state there, so that task seems to be appropriate for a function rather than a class. Could you come up with a more realistic example of what you want to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, this is not that hard of an exercise but I would go about this this way. You have a collection of books thus my class would be called `BookCollection` and it would take in the path to a XML file.

Now, what you need is the following a method to `parse` the XML, a method to `get` a book, and a method to `set` a book. So, a skeleton class would look like:

```
class BookCollection( object ):
    def __init__( self, xml_path ):
        """call the parse with the xml_path here"""
        self.bookList = []#This is a list of tuples

    def _parse( self, xml_path ):
        """This method is private and only parses the 
           xml and stores the books as tuples in a list"""

    def get( self, title ):
        """This method allows the user of this class to get 
           a book from the list of tuples"""

    def _set( self, title, cost, weight, cover=None ):
        """This method sets and adds a book tuple to the 
           list of book tuples"""
```

You do not need to represent a book as a class in python as that just over complicates the entire bit of a code thus the tuple. And, why I abstracted the XML file as a book collection.

I will not fill in the details beyond the skeleton so you can learn the rest from there.

EDIT: 
As it appears you want to also output the XML I would add a `to_xml` method to the above class that will write out your XML. If you need to remove books I would also add the associated method, but that is up for your to implement.

Comment: wow Sean, something like this am looking for :)

Comment: Then you will have to also implement that portion of the code. In my above class I have a list of tuples so you will have to convert the list of tuples into the represented XML and then you will then have to output the XML however you need/want to.